# Signal/Slots feature for different classes in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

For just one class , i declare a slot and a signal , and in slot method definition i call signal method with emit keyword. But how can i emit signals with one class to another class which has a slot.

Well i try with a button to modify  a label text. Button is created by A class (which must emit a signal) , and label is created by class B which must have a slot to modify text on it

Comment: Your question does not seem clear. Do you want to call the slot of the second class when a signal of the first class is emitted ?

Comment: then all you need to do is use the connect method as suggested by shbk. Your objects will have to inherit from QObject and you will have to include the Q_OBJECT macro so that the qt meta object pre-processing happens for that class.

Comment: @user1087135 did not helped (shbk)

Comment: here are really good examples http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html   . I have learned this stuff there. The main idea:   SLOT may be you function or be defined by default in Qt.  Signal - you just emit it. You do nothing in SIGNAL.  The main role of Signal is just to GET KNOW the SLOT that some part of code has been executed.

Comment: Looks for me that you didn't take a good look on Qt examples and tutorials that are available in Qt documentation

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you have class 1, which has a method that will be executed, and will call "emit".  When that happens, the slot of another class will find out.

definition of 1st class:

```
class songs_text {
public:
signals:
    void send_signal();
}

int songs_text:function() { 
    emit send_signal();
}
```

definition of class 2:

```
class wind {
public slots:
    void continue_job() {
    };
}
```

and your main program:

```
Wind wind(); 
Get_source songs_text(&mtempfile);

QObject::connect(&songs_text, SIGNAL(send_signal()),
    &wind, SLOT(continue_job()));
```

Comment: if i'm not wrong , a class is allowed to use signal/slot mechanism just when it inherits from QObject

Comment: Yeah, of course, you are right. Also you can inherit QWidget and QDialog etc. I just tried not to load  a story with details

Comment: when I followed your example above, I get a error with the part `void continue_job` saying `undefined reference to wind::continue_job`. Any ideas?

Comment: it seems this function wasn't implemented. Try to change it to void continue_job() {   } in the header file. Please note, that signals shouldn't be implemented, but only defined, because they are just emitted, on the other hand implementation of slots should be written by you, because you  decide what should happen when a signal was emitted.

Comment: Ohh, so slots must be implemented while signals do not. Thanks. Another follow up question is that does it matter if I connect the signal in a separate method than doing it in my main program/constructor? The thing is after catching the signal and placing it in to the slot, how would one access the information that was caught? So let say `send_signal` emits a integer `10`, and it is caught in `curent_job()` through a proper `QObject::connect` call, how can I access the integer `10` such that I can use `ui->label->setText(variable_storing_10)`? Thanks so much

Comment: this article can help to make clear some things: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html  . About the place of connection - people do it usually in constructors or main program (it would be some illogical to do it elsewhere, because connection is needed to be established only once).  Also take a look at this page http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/qobject.html#connect . It seems the first example does what you try to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Add a public method in the class named `void emitSignalBlahBlah()` to be a wrapper around the `emit` code. Then, all the other classes that need to fire this signal will access this object and call the method to do it.

Comment: i did that but i need to emit signals each time i push button

Comment: The only requirement of this approach is that whoever needs to emit the signal, needs to have access to one object/instance of this class to able to call the public method: `obj.emitSignalBlahBlah();`